# MacOSX how to ping local Windows machine by using $machine_name.local?

Tags: macos, network, dns

I have home network with 3 devices:

1. MacHighSierra
2. Windows10
3. WDMyClould

Bell Home Hub 2000 is the router, from my Mac, I can access #3 by doing

```
ping WDMyCloud.local
```

But the same thing didn't work for the Windows machine, I had to use IP. `ping Windows10.local` dosen't respond, but, `ping 192.168.2.18` works

Any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix?

Comment: On the router what does it show the names as?

Comment: Thanks for format and comment, on router the names are as listed.

Comment: What do you get by issuing the command `nslookup Windows10.local 192.168.2.1` (assuming that IP is your router, if not, insert your router IP there)?  Post the result to the orig question.

Comment: Thanks for all attentions. `nslookup Windows10.local 192.168.2.1` give: Server: 192.168.2.1 Address: 192.168.2.1#53 ** server can't find Windows10.local: NXDOMAIN`; same thing for WDMyCloud, but ping WDMyCloud.local works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out by using Wireshark, MacOSX uses MDNS protocol to browse local network. Western Digital MyCloud has MDNS server running, so it responds to MDNS Standard query. Windows10 needs to have something maybe Bonjour for Windows installed so to resolve Multicast DNS query.
https://commaster.net/content/how-resolve-multicast-dns-windows

All in all my router doesn't do local DNS service at all. And Mac uses MDNS to explore local network.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/491750), you should be able to install iTunes on the Windows device, which includes Bonjour.

It sounds like installing iTunes, and therefore Bonjour, will enable your Windows device to be accessed via a `.local` address.

You can download iTunes here; [iTunes - Download iTunes Now](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/)

Comment: iTunes has nothing to do with NetBIOS lookup functionality.

Comment: I may be incorrect, but my interpretation of the answer on superuser suggests that Bonjour, which is installed when iTunes is installed, will enable this to work. If I am incorrect, I can revise or remove my answer.

Comment: @Allan, .local is used (and advertised) by bonjour, which I'm sure you know, so I'm confused by your comment as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints, that led me to Bonjour for Windows.

Comment: @Harv `.local` isn't relegated to *only* Bonjour though Bonjour uses it.  While Bonjour is a zero-conf protocol like NetBIOS, it makes no sense adding another layer to do what is already done out of the box.  That said, I would avoid the `.local` domain when working with Windows machines because it can cause issues - go with something else, like `.home` or `.lan` or whatever makes sense for your location.

Comment: Yes, which is why "using it" through iTunes makes sense. He's already got a half-baked setup and wants the easiest way to add to it. Anyway, to each his own, thanks for clarifying your thinking behind it.